# Изменить имя файла PHP

Tags: php, файловая-система

Странно, но не смог нагуглить, как в PHP сменить имя уже загруженного файла?

Comment: [rename][1] - не катит?

   [1]:http://ua1.php.net/manual/ru/function.rename.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
copy($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "новое имя файла");
```

Вас это интересовало?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php ?